# Does filezilla close connections?

Tags: ubuntu, connection, filezilla

today I had problem while uploading files to server (using Filezilla). Server is Ubuntu 16.04.

I had to change many files on server, and they couldn't be uploaded at once, but I had to change them 1 by 1. Some 20 of them. When I finished uploading production did well, I checked my changes. Then, after 1 hour or so, I've got server 500 error on production, like: "To many connections" - forgot to print screen so I can not write exact same message here.

After few minutes of thinking I closed filezilla and when I went back to browser everything was good, again.

Coincidence?

So my questions are:

1. Does filezilla close connections after some time?
2. Does filezilla use same connection for every file?
3. Is it possible to get 500 server error because of that?
4. What is best practices with filezilla in cases like this?

Comment: Without exact error message or (even better) log file, it's difficult to help you. It's difficult to tell if the server refers to too many control or data connections.

Comment: People who downvote know that it is ok to downvote, but it is also ok to say why, so I can understand my ignorance. Thanks. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. There is a time out in the settings. Default is 20 seconds on mine but check that it is not ludicrously high.
2. The same connection is reused as long you don't disconnect and the time-out did not occur.
3. Unlikely unless you had a very long time out and you opened connections with different Filezilla processes.
4. Upload files as a bunch by multi-selecting or uploading a folder.

Too many connections could be related. Check the access logs to see where they are coming from. It could be that there is something monitoring the server and connecting to it when changes or updates happen, so if you caused changes one at a time, those processes may have repeatedly tried to connect to the server to read the changes.

ADDENDUM: In case this was not clear, points 1 and 2 together means the timeout is not a problem. If the time-out is short, the connects are closed and a new one is opened but none will stay open long. If the time out is long, the connection stays open and then it keeps getting reused, so Filezilla limits its connections to a few at a time, max.

Comment: It's not clear if the server refers to control or data connections. And in either case, FileZilla can use multiple connection (it can in case of the control connection, it must in case of the data connection). The timeout is unlikely related to the OP's problem.

Comment: Thank you @MartinPrikryl !